# why can't I read the output of this subprocess call in python?

Tags: python, shell, subprocess

I want to make a subprocess call to get the directory structure of a folder called ORIG.

Here's my code:

```
import os
from subprocess import call
# copy the directory structure of ORIG into file

f = open("outputFile.txt","r+b")
call(['find', './ORIG', '-type', 'd'], stdout=f)

a = f.read()
print(a)
```

The *call* command is working, as I see the contents of the file *outputFile.txt* when I open it:

```
./ORIG
./ORIG/child_one
./ORIG/child_one/grandchild_one
./ORIG/child_two
```

But why can't I read this/print the output?

According to Luke.py's suggestion, I tried the following also:

```
import os
import re
from subprocess import call, PIPE

# copy the directory structure of ORIG into file
# make directory structure from ORIG file in FINAL folder

process = call(['find', './ORIG', '-type', 'd'], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
stdout, stderr = process.communicate()

if stderr:
    print stderr
else:
    print stdout
```

This gives me the outut:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "feeder.py", line 9, in <module>
    stdout, stderr = process.communicate()
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'communicate'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try Popen-

You'll need to import PIPE from subprocess.

```
process = subprocess.Popen(['find', './ORIG', '-type', 'd'], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
stdout, stderr = process.communicate()

if stderr:
    print stderr
else:
    print stdout
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion and it gave me an error -- I updated my question.

Comment: That did the trick, thanks.  If you could explain why Python can't read the txt file that I successfully write with my original code, that would be helpful too.

Comment: call returns an int. not the output

Answer (score 2):

First: There is no need to call external programs. If you want to get the subdirectories of some path, there's the python function [`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk). You could use that and check each entry with `os.path.isdir`, or e.g. use `os.fwalk` and just use the directories.

If you really want to call an external program and get its stdout, usually the high level function [`subprocess.run`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) is the right choice.
You can get the stdout with:

```
subprocess.run(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout
```

Without the need for a temporary file or low level functions.

Comment: Good Stuff - I only used subprocess as the user was asking specifically

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to close and reopen the file in between writing and reading, you can use the seek command to read the file from the beginning.

```
import os
from subprocess import call
# copy the directory structure of ORIG into file

f = open("outputFile.txt","r+b")
call(['find', './ORIG', '-type', 'd'], stdout=f)

# move back to the beginning of the file
f.seek(0, 0)

a = f.read()
print(a)
```